# Which correlation algorithm or machine learning concept to use for categorizing sensor data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, correlation, real-time

I am trying to find a method where I can detect patterns from acceleration sensor data on a wheeled mobile robot, ideally using Python. I have limited experience in (supervised) machine learning and hope to get advice on what methods I should look into.

I want to categorize collisions with different objects, based on the acceleration sensor output during impact. I am expecting that different types of collisions will have different patterns and frequencies.  Eventually, the robot has to detect and categorize collisions in real-time to perform the appropriate action.

Could someone point me in the right direction which machine learning programs exist where 'fingerprints' can be uploaded, and based on correlations with the real-time sensor data, recognize and categorize the event?